# SAS array define error

Tags: arrays, sas

```
%let ng = 4;

data a1;
set a2;
array cur{&ng} cur1-cur&ng.;
do i = 1 to &ng.;
if (_n_ = (i-1)*5 + 1) then cur[i] = Val; 
end;
run;
```

**Error msg**

```
ERROR: Missing numeric suffix on a numbered variable list (cur1-cur).
ERROR: Too few variables defined for the dimension(s) specified for the array cur.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (, ;, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_, _CHAR_, _NUMERIC_.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Why `do i = 1 to &ng.` and `cur{&ng}` work but `cur1-cur&ng.` generates errors?

Comment: trying your code, `cur1-cur&ng` resolves just fine here. Saying that, I had to comment out your set statement and add an `end;` to close your do loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works fine for me, however I have encountered this problem where I've created a macro variable (in this case ng) with the `proc sql into:` or `call symput` methods, as these set a default length of 8 and pad the value with spaces.  I suspect in your actual code the macro variable ng is being created in one of these ways.

To get around this, try adding `%trim` as below.

```
array cur[&ng.] cur1-cur%trim(&ng.);
```

You also need to add an `end` statement to close the `do` loop.

Comment: Awesome @keith. It's created by `proc sql into:`. The original code is too long and I didn't check how the `ng` was defined.

Comment: It sounds by defining the length I can avoid such problems.

Comment: You can also use %trim when the macro variable is created, which will also fix it

Comment: Nice catch.  You can also add `separated by ''` to eliminate the spacing... ie. `proc sql noprint inobs=1; select age into :test1 from sashelp.class; select age into :test2 separated by '' from sashelp.class; quit;` And to test the results: `%put "&test1";%put "&test2";`

Comment: Using `proc sql into`, how can I use %trim when the macro variable is created?

Comment: My mistake, it doesn't work in this instance.  I've used it where I've created a range of macro variables (e.g. for 'x1 - x&ng.' you can use `x1 - x%trim(&ng.)`).  I'd go with the suggestion from @Robert, i.e. `separated by ''`